# Now in Android Application Structure (kts) need to add Parcelable plugin to some modules and features

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, parcelable, android-multi-module

I'm using the "Now in Android" multi module application as my "learn by example" base however I've hit another snag from a requirement to my data classes to support Parceable.

As of the moment I need a data class present in core:module:data to be Parcelable, however I am struggling to add the plugin to the module's build.gradle.kts.

Here's what I've tried as per [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize)

1. in module - build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.endviscrmux.android.library)
    alias(libs.plugins.endviscrmux.android.library.jacoco)
    alias(libs.plugins.endviscrmux.android.hilt)
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
}

android {
    namespace = "co.uk.btcserv.apps.cerpsys.endvis.crm.data"
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            isIncludeAndroidResources = true
            isReturnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":core:common"))
    implementation(project(":core:database"))
    implementation(project(":core:model"))
    implementation(project(":core:network"))
    implementation(project(":core:datastore"))
}
```

2. in libs.versions.toml

```
[versions]
kotlin = "1.9.21"

[libraries]
kotlin-gradlePlugin = { group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "kotlin" }

[plugins]
```

However, the data class fails to find the @Parcelize annotation required imports.

kindly assist

Comment: no need to tell people that you're still new to android, good answers are expected to be written in a way that anyone can follow and understand, so if someone gives you an answer and you need more than that, you're welcome to comment on it

Comment: To be honest the imports seem alright, did you try to invalidate the caches?

Comment: also, are you sure you're applying the plugin to the correct module?

Comment: Thanks both,

The problem was related to the module I was aiming to apply this to. And the custom android plugin that was previously applied.

I need to spend more time to understand the crux of the plugins present in the build-logic:convention module which is shared across the modules and features.

For now I will do some refactoring to unblock this Parcelable usecase then understudy the plugins.

If you do have any documentation to share around the build-logic and custom plugins implementation for the Now in Android app, kindly share too.

Thanks both

Answer (score 0):

See my last comment which suggests there's a need to further understand the build-logic : convention's module for it's plugin's usecases

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).